# Notice: Undefined property: Sm\MegaMenu\Block\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Tab\Form::$_wysiwygConfig

Tags: error, magento2.3

PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Sm\MegaMenu\Block\Adminhtml\MenuItems\Edit\Tab\Form::$_wysiwygConfig

[image]

https://github.com/goodten/form/blob/master/Form.php

Comment: The error message looks pretty clear. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Open

> app/code/Sm/MegaMenu/Block/Adminhtml/MenuItems/Edit/Tab/Form.php

Now search $_wysiwygConfig. Now add following code:

```
$_wysiwygConfig = null;
```

Comment: Don't have this word in Form.php

Comment: Show your From.php

Comment: Can you update your question? Can't access your file.

Comment: https://github.com/goodten/form/blob/master/Form.php

Thankyou.

Comment: Please add code here and question  your From.php